# How to return maximum numeric value if text is in array with MAXA()?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

**UPDATED**
MAXA() not returns maximum numeric value if text is in array, as expected according https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094016

> MAXA Returns the maximum numeric value in a dataset.

- and even sample is with error - returns `#VALUE`, not maximum numeric

Example:
formula `MAXA({1;20;300;"#VALUE!";"Google"})` gives 300
but if values `1; 20; 300; #VALUE!; Google` are in cells A9:A13
having array `=MAXA(A9:A13)` gives `#VALUE!`

To reproduce: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17yJ33Zx24eC7-n-a7EaR9f9knhlQUaKYHEk2ghzZXAI/edit#gid=1923535662

Where is the problem?

Comment: As written, this question is low quality and IMO should not be migrated to another site.

Comment: @Twisty You are welcome to suggest your edited version if able (but I don't understand reason to "be migrated to another site")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass MAXA() character strings directly (vs having a text value in a range of cells), but can pass numeric string such as "35". You can however pass non-numeric character strings as part of a range of cells (see example below) and it will assign them a value of zero.

The function will return something like `#VALUE!` or `#NAME?` as an error message if it cannot calculate the function parameters.
If you mouse over the value it returns in your example it will tell you why it failed.

```
Function MAXA parameter 4 expects number values. 
But '#VALUE!' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.
```

Examples:
`MAXA(3,4,"5")`  valid, it is a numeric string 
`MAXA(3,4,"five")` invalid, as it is not a numeric string 
`MAXA(A1:A6)` valid, "text" gets set to 0, when A1 to A6 looks like

```
 A1 | -2
 A2 | -4
 A3 | -2
 A4 | -5
 A5 | -1
 A6 | text
```

Source: the [support document](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094016) you linked.
 Note they show in one of their examples that the result of 
`=MINA(A2:A6, "Google")` is `#VALUE!`

Comment: I dont' get - according https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013?hl=en
To allow text values, use MAXA.

Comment: and "Any referenced text value in any of the value arguments will be assigned the numeric value 0 for the purpose of this function."

Comment: It is a little odd how it words it, but testing it you can have text in a range of cells and it does count text as 0. So a range like A2:A8 with text gets assigned zero but you can't pass directly as a parameter.

Comment: probably #VALUE! is a kind of a "stop" word

Comment: Yes it's like excel if it can't calculate the formula it gives #VALUE! as an error message.

Comment: your statement 'You can't pass MAXA() character strings' is wrong - this function is for mixed datasets [MAXA() Returns the maximum of a list of arguments, including text and logical entries.](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_MAXA_function)

Comment: and the same from [Excel help: arguments can be the following: numbers; names, arrays, or references that contain numbers; text representations of numbers; or logical values, such as TRUE and FALSE, in a reference.] (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MAXA-function-814bda1e-3840-4bff-9365-2f59ac2ee62d)

Comment: @AndriuZ You can't pass character strings directly unless they are purely numeric, updated the answer to be more clear. Also you linked excel and open office support article, when the question is about google spreadsheets.

Comment: FYI link to OO is provided by [Google Sheets offical help](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en). But where did you got  'can't pass character strings directly' and what you mean 'directly' - could you provide source and sample?

Comment: @AndriuZ I edited the answer with more clear examples, and directly means as one of the parameters of the function vs a value in a range of cells.

Comment: Your point is that =MAXA(A4:A6) is not the same as =MAXA(-5;-1;"text")? I'snt that a bug?

Comment: @AndriuZ I wouldn't think so. The first allows you flexibility of not have to guarantee that your cell range doesn't contain text. The second is passing a string on purpose which is not defined what happens in that case. So there is really no reason to do the second case. You are hard coding the text in, so if you want it to evaluate to zero why not just type 0.